# What are file (or directory) names starting with a '#'?

Tags: linux, file-management

These appear to be special files because you can not cp them. These files (and directory) were encountered in docker image mysql/mysql-server:latest. These
files are:

> -rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql   196608 Apr 12 17:26 #ib_16384_0.dblwr
> -rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql  8585216 Apr 12 17:24 #ib_16384_1.dblwr
> drwxr-x--- 2 mysql mysql     4096 Apr 12 17:24 #innodb_temp/

Comment: Where are they? Can you give a full path example of these files?

Comment: These files are in /var/lib/mysql (the mysql data directory). Two files (.dblwr) and one directory.

Comment: Can you add an `ls -lF /var/lib/mysql | grep '#'` to your question?

Comment: Found in mysql docs "A hash symbol '#' is automatically prefixed to the specified directory name to avoid conflicts with schema names." But that does not explain why the filesystem treats them as special.

Comment: I meant the output of that command of course, not the litteral overtyping. :-)

Comment: The files should not be treated as special. But you need to quote these file names or escape the `#` with a  balckslash, otherwise the shell will treat the rest of the line as comment. So, for example `ls -l #filename` will ls the whole directory and `ls -l '#filename'` will give you only one line.

Comment: An alternative technique is to prefix them with "./"